# Web crawler script not working for calender events

Tags: php, web-crawler

I have written a web crawler script 
Code is::

```
<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$target_url = "http://jvlaunchcalendar.com/calendar/";
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($target_url);
$ret = $html->find('div[class=fc-event-inner'); 
//to print the caleder events similar code //works for other sites like flipcat.com
foreach($ret as $post)
{
    echo $post.'<br />';
}
echo $html;// to print the calender of jvlaunchcalendar.com site
?>
```

This script works fine for other sites .
But I want all calender events of http://jvlaunchcalendar.com/calendar/ page but this script doesn't display any event gives  empty calender.
Please help me to get the events of calender .

Regards.

Comment: seems like it doesnt contains any div with such class.

Comment: output whole `$html` after loading content and see what you'll get.

Comment: div is there please check again  i have pasted this class from calender. But when i want to fetch complete page that is $html  then it doesn't show any calender event empty calender.

Comment: so what i'm talking about. calendar loads from ajax request. so when you "loading" page its empty.

Comment: How  you come to know calendar events are coming from ajax.And can you  tell me any solution please.

Comment: Hm..you call yourself "wordpress developer"? :) I can explain all this, but it's too much text to write here in comments.

Comment: Please tell me what you know i need this solution its client work .

Comment: ok call me on skype itman.green

Comment: i mean.. any chat where you can write a lot. but i dont have icq, only skype :)

Comment: ok i know but my office doesn't allow me for this.

Comment: poor Indian programmers...

Answer (score 3):

When you're trying to `$html->load_file($target_url);` you got empty page with no events coz events are loaded with ajax.

Simple solution to get events: track ajax url calling and load it, not page. (i checked, it returns `json` data, all is ok).

But it's not good. Other ways - do it inside WordPress with native calendar functions.

Comment: i am using only php.I will try your solution now

Comment: Can you tell me little bit more .

Comment: little bit more is: 1. open developing tools in browser; 2. trace ajax call; 3. find out url with data; 4. load this url in your php script; 5. Profit!

Comment: so what? you have `json` data with events. quest completed. problem solved.